# Extract multiple substrings between 2 characters [ ] and replace in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
line = '<td id="bar_h" style="width: [SUBSTR1]%;">Hector [SUBSTR2]% ([SUBSTR3])</td>'
```

I need the above line to be parsed like below*

```
line = '<td id="bar_h" style="width: ' + dict[SUBSTR1] + '%;">Hector ' + dict[SUBSTR2] + '% (' + dict[SUBSTR3] +  ')</td>'
```

The substring between characters [ ] are keys in my dictionary dict. Below is my code to parse it, it can successfully get 2 substrings but fails if there are more than 2 in one line. I have several lines and multiple keys embedded in the lines between [ ].

```
char1 = '['
char2 = ']'
modHtmlLine = ''
if (line.find('[') != -1):
     hKey = line[line.find(char1)+1 : line.find(char2)] # Extract Substring
     hKey = hKey.strip()
     charIndex = 0
     start = 0
     firstTime = 0
     for ch in line:
         if (ch == '['):
             if (firstTime == 0):
                 modHtmlLine += str(dicthtml[mainKey][hKey])
                 firstTime = 1
             else:
                 h1Key = line[charIndex+1 : line.find(char2, charIndex+1)] # Extract Substring
                 modHtmlLine += str(dicthtml[mainKey][h1Key])
                 firstTime = 2
                 start = 1
         elif (start == 0):
             modHtmlLine += ch
         elif (ch == ']'):
             start = 0
         charIndex += 1
     lineList.append(modHtmlLine)
 else:
     lineList.append(line)
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? What is your question? (Hint: "How do I do this?" is not the right question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all occurrences of `"[KEY]"` in a string, with its dictionaries values, by applying the `sub()` function of the `re` module, and passing a callback function as its `repl` parameter.

```
import re


d = {'SUBSTR1': 'value 1', 'SUBSTR2': 'value 2', 'SUBSTR3': 'value 3'}
line = '<td id="bar_h" style="width: [SUBSTR1]%;">Hector [SUBSTR2]% ([SUBSTR3])</td>'

result = re.sub('\[([\w]+)\]', lambda x: d[x.groups()[0]], line)
```

**output for `print(result)`:**

```
'<td id="bar_h" style="width: value 1%;">Hector value 2% (value 3)</td>'
```

Comment: Works like a charm. These couple of lines just cleaned up a lot of code.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool! I don't get why they closed your question, tho. It seemed to be clear enough what you were trying to accomplish...